# Simultaneously adding multiple search results from Catalog into ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1

System spec: ArcInfo 10.1

I have performed a search on an indexed file geodatabase, looking for feature classes with the word "building" in their name.

I either need to add all of these to a blank map, or copy/export them all to a new location.
I was hoping that after performing the search I would be able to select all of the returned results and add them to the map, but it appears that I have to add them one at a time.  There's thousands of feature classes returned, so adding them one by one isn't really an option.

Am I missing something really simple? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: How are you performing the search?

Comment: Using the search tab function in ArcMap desktop

Comment: By the "search tab function" do you mean the Search window?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to use arcpy/python for this task.  The workflow would go something like this:

1. Iterate through geodatabase and do a wildcard search for all features with name "building"
2. Loop through the returned list from step one and add each found case to a map ([Add Layer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s300000025000000)).
3. Then, save the map e.g. `mxd.saveACopy(r"C:\Project\Project2.mxd")`

Answer (score 2):

Working from @artwork21's suggestion I made this, however I'm having issues adding the FC to the TOC >1
*edited to account for duplicates 
For some reason cannot name the layer the same as the fc...perhaps someone can help with this?

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
import sys
import traceback

#Set path to geodatabase
env.workspace="G://Test//test.mdb"
#Path to your mxd
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
#wildcard the query only list feature classes that contain it
fclist = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*building*")
#print all feature classes containing building
print fclist
counter = 0
try:

    for fc in fclist:
    #if this fc already exists then rename       
        if arcpy.Exists(fc) in df:
            print fc +  "Exists in dataframe"
            counter =+1
            string = str(fc) + "_" + str(counter)
            arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc, string)
            layer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(string)
        else:
            counter =+1
            string = str(fc) + "_" + str(counter)
            print string + "does not exist"
            arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc, string)
            layer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(string)
            layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers (mxd)


    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
    arcpy.RefreshTOC
except:
    print ("Error occurred")
    tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
    tbinfo = traceback.format_tb(tb)[0]
    pymsg = "PYTHON ERRORS:\nTraceback Info:\n" + tbinfo + "\nError Info:\n    " + \
        str(sys.exc_type)+ ": " + str(sys.exc_value) + "\n"
    msgs = "GP ERRORS:\n" + arcpy.GetMessages(2 )+ "\n"
    print (pymsg)
    print (msgs)
```

Comment: +1 for attempting to Answer but w.r.t. "For some reason cannot name the layer the same as the fc...perhaps someone can help with this?", I recommend that you research/ask this as a separate question rather than asking a "question within an Answer".

Comment: @PolyGeo Thanks, that's a good point. I was hoping it would be enough for OP and if not someone could adjust. I looked around and couldn't find much on the subject, for now adding a number to the end of the name works.
I will edit if I can find more information today.